# My flashplugin doesn't work on firefox

Tags: firefox, flash

I have ubuntu 14.04. I'm using firefox to browse the web and it worked properly but just a few days ago after I used `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get update` it keeps telling me to install flashplugin. I even reinstalled my flashplugin but it still doesn't work. What should I do ?!

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg --status flashplugin-installer` and `dpkg --status adobe-flashplugin`?

Comment: It said that adobe-flashplugin isn't installed ! I tried to install it with apt-get but it said package adobe-flashplugin isn't available and it has no installation candidate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to

1. [enable Canonical's partner package repository](/a/14633/175814),
2. check for new package updates (`sudo apt-get update`), and
3. install [adobe-flashplugin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/adobe-flashplugin) [image: Install adobe-flashplugin].

([source](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-adobe-flash-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/))

Answer (score 4):

You can get the newest version of flash player to firefox. Just do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
sudo mkdir -p /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/libpepflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash
```

and then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
```

This will install pepper flash (google chrome's flash player) to firefox.

Comment: Well, I used that and now it stopped asking for installing flash but instead of showing pictures and things like that it just show a blank box which says "Failed to load libpepflashplayer.so". and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my answer...you need ibpepflashplayer.so (pepper flash library)...

Comment: This is not the recommended way to install flash player for Firefox on Linux, because Firefox doesn't support PPAPI plug-ins (yet).

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks! And it is now in the official Ubuntu 14.04 repo  http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/pepper-flash-player-installer-for.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Flash player in Firefox these are the steps.

If you want to install *Flash plugin(11.2)* you can run

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

But, if you want to install *Flash plugin (14.0 alpha)* you have to add repository and run following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
```

Note: If you want to run the ***Flash plugin (14.0 alpha)*** on Firefox, you’ll have to download and install [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/), else, the plugin won’t run on Firefox (Yes, in order to run it on Firefox, you have to install Chrome).