# flash plugin error for streaming website

Tags: flash

I've recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and installed flash plugin. But when I went to live streaming website the result is like in the image. So tell me how to fix this issue as I am new to the ubuntu operating system.

[image]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/521234/my-flashplugin-doesnt-work-on-firefox